# cellspacing differences between different versions of IE

Tags: html, css, tablelayout

I've noticed, that unless I use a cellspacing attribute set to 0px on my tables, they render slightly differently in IE8 depending on compatability mode.  When set to on, the table cell spacing appears larger.  I can mitigate this by setting cellspacing to 0, but I want to do it with css, and I can't find anything that causes the exact same behavior as cellspacing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

might be worth trying...

```
<TABLE style="border-collapse: collapse;">
```

or

```
table {border-collapse: collapse;}
```

in your css file.

(It's the same thing, just in two dif places.)